# When to use Unconfined in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

When would I choose to use Dispatchers.Unconfined? Is when it doesn't really matter where the coroutine should run? So you let the coroutine to choose the thread pool as it better suits?

And how does it differ from Dispatchers.Default? Is it that when running the Default dispatcher is always within a specific thread pool defined as the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The unconfined dispatcher is appropriate for coroutines which neither consume CPU time nor update any shared data (like UI) confined to a specific thread.

So, I'd use it in non-IO, UI or computation heavy situations basically :D.
I think the nunmber of use-cases for this is pretty low, but I'd think of an operation which isn't heavy, but still for some reason you'd like it to run on a different thread.

[Here's a link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#unconfined-vs-confined-dispatcher) for how it actually works.

`Dispatchers.Default` is really different, and it's mostly used for heavy CPU operations.
This is because, it actually dispatches works to a thread pool with a number of threads equal to the number of CPU cores, and it's at least 2. This way developers can leverage the full capacity of the cpu when doing heavy computational work.

Answer (score 4):

> So you let the coroutine to choose the thread pool as it better suits?

That's not really how `Unconfined` works. The best way to understand it is that it is a "no-op" dispatcher that doesn't actually do any dispatch at all. Wherever you call `continuation.resume()`, that's where the coroutine resumes execution — within that very call. When the `resume()` call returns, it means the coroutine has either suspended again or completed.

In normal programming, you usually call `continuation.resume()` from a callback and it is not your code that runs the callback, so you don't actually have any control over the thread where your coroutine will resume. It is not advisable to use the `Unconfined` dispatcher when resuming from a callback provided by a library that is not under your control.

`Unconfined` is really a special-cased tool you can use when building a coroutine execution environment yourself, or in other custom scenarios. Basically, you should use it only when you are actively looking for a way to disable the normal dispatching mechanism.